# stylecop with VSTS build defnition

Tags: azure-devops, stylecop, build-definition

I'm using VSTS with git. I'm creating a build definition for one of the projects and I want to run stylecop rules as part of build definition. I have a custom stylecop.settings file. I came across 
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=richardfennellBM.BM-VSTS-StyleCop-Task but I wanted to know if there is any other alternative available. Can someone help. Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can also [setup StyleCop MSBuild Integration](https://stylecop.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Setting%20Up%20StyleCop%20MSBuild%20Integration&referringTitle=Documentation) to run automatically whenever the code is built.